# Grammatical structure of "chacun le vit différemment"

Tags: sens

"Le stress n’est pas quelque chose de mesurable, car **chacun le vit différemment**."

I don't understand the grammatical structure of the phrase, though  I understand the meaning.

Comment: You're not spelling it right, it's *vit* (third-person indicative present of *vivre*), not *vie*. Spelled this way, does it make more sense?

Comment: @qoba Thank you. Can you elaborate? I'm still as clueless as before.

Comment: @Dashoes. You may if you please correct the spelling of " vie".  A "t" is required, for here we are dealing with the verb " vivre".  "Vie" ( with an " e") is a noun : " la vie". - True , sometimes, a verb can have the same spelling as some noun ( ex " que je voie "  - verb: " voire" in subj. mood  -  and " la voie = le chemin, la route " ) but here it is not the case.

Answer (score 5):

> Le stress n’est pas quelque chose de mesurable, car **chacun le vit différemment**

The meaning of "vit" there is "to experience".

Let me try to explain the grammatical structure of the bolded part by a progression:

> Chacun vit (everybody experiences)
>
> Chacun vit le stress (everybody experiences stress)
>
> Chacun vit le stress différemment (everybody experiences stress differently)
>
> Chacun le vit différemment (everybody experiences it differently -- the object being understood from context)

Answer (score 1):

From a grammatical point of view because who asked, considering "chacun le vit différemment" :

- **chacun** is the *subject*
- **le** is a *direct object* (referring to *le stress*)
- **vit** is the *verb*
- **différemment** is an *adverb* (precising how people "vivent le stress")

And in fact, the key element of this sentence is the coordinating conjunction "car" which binds the second part of the sentence to the first as a cause.

About the meaning or translation, @qoba is right.

Answer (score 1):

The structure is

Subject + Complément d'Object Direct + Verbe + Complément circonstantiel de manière.

Note that : "adverb" is not a grammatical function ( but what french grammarians call a " word nature" : noun, adjective, adverb, pronoun, etc. ). The " nature" of a word never changes. Its grammatical function varies depending the sentence in which it is used.

Chacun --> pronom indéfini

le --> pronom personnel "il" in the accusative ( direct object) case ; here this pronoun has as referent the noun phrase " le stress"

vit --> verbe

différemment --> adverbe de manière